# how does the conditional probability with the MAP approach in linear regression work?

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood

In order to derive the MAP approach of linear regression, we write:

$P(\theta|X, Y) = P(Y|\theta, X)P(\theta)$. Note that I disregarded the denominator since it does not depend on $\theta$. What I don't understand is that how: $P(Y, X, \theta)$ became $P(Y|\theta, X)P(\theta)$ in the numerator. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you have $P(X,Y,\theta)=P(Y|X,\theta)P(\theta|X)P(X)$, but $P(\theta|X)=P(\theta)$ is assumed because the true model parameter does not depend on data. And $P(X)$ doesn't matter like denominator because it's free of data. Best to say
$$P(\theta|X,Y)\propto P(Y|X,\theta)P(\theta)$$